# Optimize Tag based search in Android recyclerView with 1k+ items.

Tags: android, search, optimization, tags, android-recyclerview

My Android app has a `recyclerView` of 1500-1700 items in the forms of cards, each card representing some textual data. Each card has certain tags on them [for example] #2016 #India #blue #music etc. Cards can have multiple tags.

I want to add a tag based search to this recyclerView. For example, when "2016 music" is searched, it should only show that cards that has both these tags, "2016" and "music".

All I can think of is, whenever a tag is added to the search bar, I go through all the items and remove all those cards that doesn't have that following tag. But Scanning 1500 items every time a tag is added to the search bar must consume a lot of time.

What would be the optimum way to implement a tag based search in `recyclerViews` with too many items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All I can think of is, whenever a tag is added to the search bar, I go through all the items and remove all those cards that doesn't have that following tag

That is definitely a bad approach. The ideal way is to update the adapter. ie when user searches for a `TAG` , use `Loader` to retrieve data from your content provider, and update the adater's data and invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

- Now there are other aspects to this question, like what data storage options to use for the fastest way, eg(mysql,realm,etc). Which you should choose according to your data size and other factors, which should be asked as a different question if you do not find much info after research(chances are scarce).

#### TIP

When building projects like these, it would be a best practice to follow an architecture, preferably `MVC` or `MVP`, which would make development and debugging easy, also would make the data flow perfect.
[image]

Links with further info on `MVC` and `MVP` is provided below.Choose which suits best for your requirement. Hope it helps.

- [Model View Controller pattern](http://www.bogotobogo.com/DesignPatterns/mvc_model_view_controller_pattern.php)
- [MVP architecture in Android](https://medium.com/@kenjuw/mvp-architecture-in-android-development-3d63cc32707a#.adjf8x2jy)
- [Writing better Android apps with MVP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4L7G1uaQ67s)
- [Android Application Architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlkJzgjzL0c)

Comment: I didn't know about loaders. Now clear. And for storing purpose I am thinking of using JSON. Reading your further links in the answer..